# SAS - deleting duplicates on multiple variables

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete the observations in my data set that are the same across multiple variables.

For example

RID           Admission Date        End Date 
 
1           Jan 1 2014          Jan 3 2014> 
 
1         January 1           Jan 3 2014  
1          March 2 2014        March 5 2014
2        July 1 2014        July 8 2014 
2         July 1 2014        July 8 2014
2        August 9 2014         August 24 2014

I would want to keep all unique admissions for each RID, but delete any observations with the same RID and the same admission/end dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
PROC SORT DATA=work.yourdatasetin OUT=work.datasetout NODUPLICATES ;
  BY rid ;
RUN ;
```

Something like this might also work.

```
proc sql;
create table work.yourdatasetout as 
select distinct
    *
from 
    work.yourdatasetin;
quit;
```

Comment: I believe you meant to use the `nodupe` option instead of the `nodupkey` option?  Dupe RID records are ok as long as they have different dates.

Comment: Yes Robert, I would like to keep RID records that have the same RID but different dates. Can you explain to me the nodupe option/.

Comment: Surely the `NODUPKEY` option will work if RID, Admission_Date and End_Date are included in the `BY` statement?

Comment: @Keith Actually your suggestion is a better way to do it as it will allow you to keep additional columns (if there are any) in the results.